# Font awesome percentage width stacked icon

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I want to achieve the following effect with CSS:

[image]

This star icon is a font. I would like to define the width of the orange background by percents, so 50% should be the perfect half of the star.

For now, I did the following:

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="star star-under fa fa-star"></span>
    <span class="star star-over fa fa-star"></span>
</div>
```

And:

```
.container
{
    font-size: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.star
{
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.star-under
{
    color: #ddd;
}

.star-over
{
    color: #f80;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 30%;
}
```

The problem is that I need to provide the width and height in order to use % of width. And if I skip the container's width and height, it displays nothing, because it contains absolutely positioned children.

This % value is calculated on server side, so I'd rather keep it inline, like this:

```
<span class="star star-over fa fa-star" style="width: 62%;"></span>
```

What is the most flexible way to do this? By most flexible I mean the one that doesn't make it necessary to provide any width nor height.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vco9r2rt/3/

Comment: @Moogs that's awesome, but I need to make this width inline - it's calculated in my server script. I could of course put CSS to my HTML file, but I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vco9r2rt/4/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the container to `display:inline-block`, and only set the top icon to `position:absolute`.

```css
.container {
  font-size: 200px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.star-under {
  color: #ddd;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.star-over {
  color: #f80;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 70%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <span class="star star-under fa fa-star"></span>
  <span class="star star-over fa fa-star"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually tried similar way, but got my results unequal. The text positions didn't match if one was put without `position: absolute` and the second was. I need to inspect all inherited styles.

Comment: I noticed that too ealier, so I added `vertical-align` and it seems to be working good.

Comment: Ha, that's an idea! I will try that and select your answer if it works! Thanks mate.

Comment: You can remove the container and just nest the over icon inside the under icon. https://jsfiddle.net/vco9r2rt/4/

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys :) I needed to keep the container anyway, because I'm having some paddings there, that must stay paddings (not margins). With paddings, my % would be not precise. But now I use my over element inside the under element, which is more convenient. And thanks for `vertical-align`, Pangloss :)